# How to get top 3 value of record in old version MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

e.g. 
In DB:
1
2
3
4
5
5

I want get:
5
5
4
3

I use this:

```
select *
from product
where price in(
    select price from product group by price order by price desc limit 3
)
order by price desc
```

But MySQL response this error

`#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Any other way to do same thing?

Comment: How old is old?

Comment: Version is 5.6.43-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: What about using `JOIN`?

Comment: Why are you even nesting a SELECT statement?

Comment: Try something like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iQvnuV7tipWojk9Eq5ZqDh/1

Comment: It is work, but I don't understand why, why left join same table, and why `count(distinct p2.price) <= 2` will make it work?

Comment: Something like this `SELECT *
FROM product INNER JOIN (SELECT price FROM product GROUP BY price ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 3) b ON product.price=b.price
ORDER BY product.price DESC`

Comment: But it is not work if some record is null, I added `and p1.price is not null`, but still not work. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6jnJDQo75tm1phaPcR8Pe7/1

Comment: `SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN (SELECT price FROM product GROUP BY price ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 3) b ON product.price=b.price ORDER BY product.price DESC` I think this is better answer, no null problem and easy to understand.